# SQL select the max from each group and given them different lables

Tags: postgresql

For the following tables:

```
-- People
 id | category | count
----+----------+-------
  1 | a        |     2
  1 | a        |     3
  1 | b        |     2
  2 | a        |     2
  2 | b        |     3
  3 | a        |     1
  3 | a        |     2
```

I know that I can find the max count for each id in each category by doing:

```
SELECT id, category, max(count) from People group by category, id;
```

With result:

```
 id | category | max
----+----------+-------
  1 | a        |     3
  1 | b        |     2
  2 | a        |     2
  2 | b        |     3
  3 | a        |     2
```

But what if now I want to label the max values differently, like:

```
 id | max_b_count | max_a_count
----+-------------+------------
  1 | 2           |     3
  2 | 3           |     2
  3 | Null        |     2
```

Should I do something like the following?

```
WITH t AS (SELECT id, category, max(count) from People group by category, id)
SELECT t.id, t.count as max_a_count from t where t.category = 'a'
FULL OUTER JOIN t.id, t.count as max_b_count from t where t.category = 'b'
on t.id;
```

It looks weird to me.

Comment: Please tag only one database. MySQL and Postgersql are two different databases.

Comment: Your JOIN syntax is wrong so your proposal is a code that does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the exact use case why the *filter_clause* was added to the [Aggregate Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES)

With *filter_clause* you may limit which row you aggregate

```
aggregate_name ( * ) [ FILTER ( WHERE filter_clause ) ]
```

Your example

```
SELECT id, 
max(count)  filter (where category = 'a') as max_a_count,
max(count)  filter (where category = 'b') as max_b_count
from People
group by id
order by 1;

id|max_a_count|max_b_count|
--+-----------+-----------+
 1|          3|          2|
 2|          2|          3|
 3|          2|           |
```

Comment: I like this one.

Comment: You are welcome @VBoka and sorry for my highly "educational" comment ...

Comment: Not a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you can do it:

```
with T as (select id, category, max(count_ab) maks
from people
group by id, category
order by id)
select t3.id
       , (select t1.maks from T t1 where category = 'b' and t1.id = t3.id) max_b_count 
       , (select t2.maks from T t2 where category = 'a' and t2.id = t3.id) max_a_count 
from T t3
group by t3.id
order by t3.id
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/KPfGTSVs)

Also, as you can see, I have changed the name of the column count to count_ab because it is not a good practice to use keywords as columns names.

Comment: Yes, this is *one way*. But in examination you'll be probably asked, why do you choose twice `group by` and twice to `join` if a single `group by` works fine?